# receive half message via ssl channel in c

Tags: c, linux, ssl, tcp, communication

my question is can I receive a half message with the code below?
If I want to send a message like: "MESSAGE\n"
Can that happen I receive only M character if the channel is slowly?

and the code part:

```
fd.fd = c->socket;
fd.events = POLLIN;
bzero(received, sizeof(received));

result = poll(&fd, 1, time);
if(result > 0)
{
  i = SSL_read ( (SSL *)c->sslHandle, (char*)received, INCOMING_BUFFERSIZE);
  result = SSL_get_error(c->sslHandle, i);
   ...
}
```

Because I though I receive nothing until the the "\n" symbol is not received.

How can make sure I accept message only with \n at end of that.

thanks the help,

Tamas

EDIT: the version I am using is 1.0.1c

Answer (score 0):

The socket is stream-based which means that you get a stream of bytes, not a message. Consequently with one recv() call you can get from 1 to all bytes of the data you've sent. You need to put the data to some intermediate buffer and analyze the buffer for some markers (\n in your case).

Comment: I read the manual which says:
The data are received in records (with a maximum record size of 16kB for SSLv3/TLSv1). Only when a record has been completely received, it can be processed (decryption and check of integrity)....
And therefore I suppose if I wrote a message like "MESSAGE\n" I have to receive that or nothing. Is it true?

Comment: @Tomi that's about SSL/TLS records, not about your message. And SSL layer knows nothing about partitioning of your data stream.